# RegEx in JavaScript for hours and minutes format

Tags: javascript

I will check in JavaScript if an expression meets the requirements. The expression should have this format:

```
min 1 number, max 3 numbers (:) min 0 number, max 3 numbers
e.g. 12:3, or 443:45 or 12, ...
```

I have tried this in a jsfiddle but currently with no success.
Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

[My RegEx](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22842/)

Comment: Code related to your question goes **in** your question, not just linked. That's why SO wouldn't let you post this with a fiddle link until you (incorrectly) marked your example as code. Please don't work around the system, work *with* it.

Comment: You need to escape slashes in your regexes if they are defined in JS string literals. Eg: `\\d{1,3}`

Comment: [`new RegExp('^\\d{1,3}(:\\d{1,2})?$')`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n82k70um/) or use RegEx literal syntax. `/^\d{1,3}(:\d{1,2})?$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex `/(\d{1,3}:?(\d{1,3}))/`

demo https://regex101.com/r/aU6cM1/1

```
var re = /(\d{1,3}:?(\d{1,3}))/gm; 
var str = '\ne.g. 12:3, or 443:45 or 12, ...';
var subst = ''; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```